# Redis: set key value [EX seconds] [PX milliseconds] [NX|XX] gives syntax error

Tags: redis

I was trying to set a expiry with a key in redis. I am able to do it with SETEX,but reading the documentation I see it can be done with SET key value [EX seconds] [PX milliseconds] [NX|XX] as well. However trying with SET I get a syntax error.

Syntax I am using: SET key1 hello 100

I am using Redis version 3.2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct syntax is like SET myKey myValue ex 100 NX.

Comment: Thank you. Confused me several times